# import dataset into neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to import a dataset (csv file) in Neo4J.
I'm on Ubuntu 16 and I'm following [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) guide:

When I do this:

```
neo4j_home$ ./bin/neo4j-import --into path_to_target_directory --nodes movies.csv --nodes actors.csv --relationships roles.csv
```

I get (in ubuntu terminal) this error:

```
Input error: Directoy '<my target directory here>' not writable: No such file or directory
```

Can you help me? This is my following structure under `usr/share/neo4j` (folder name are in bold):

```
- bin
  - neo4j
  - neo4j-admin
  - neo4j-import // what I use for importing
  - neo4j-shared.sh
  - neo4j-shell 

- import (I created this directory which holds the file to import)
  - MyTestDir
    - first.csv
    - second.csv
    - third.csv

for completeness: I also have these 2 folders
- lib (some jar files here) 
- tools 
  - config-migrator.jar
```

How do I import first.csv, second.csv and third.csv into neo4j?

I tried with (note i'm inside bin folder): `./neo4j-import --into <dont know what write here> --nodes ../import/MyTestDir/first.csv ../import/MyTestDir/second.csv ../import/MyTestDir/third.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the user you're executing `neo4j-import` as doesn't have write access to the folder you're importing into? Have you tried `--into /usr/share/neo4j/data/graph.db` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The `--into` refers to your database directory which is `/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/MY_GRAPH` in Linux. Make sure you have full permission on `usr/share/neo4j` directory.  So your import should be like this :

```
sudo neo4j-import --into /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/MY_GRAPH  --stacktrace --nodes "/usr/share/neo4j/import/MyTestDir/first.csv,/usr/share/neo4j/import/MyTestDir/second.csv,/usr/share/neo4j/import/MyTestDir/third.csv"
```